# How can I export an animated GIF in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, gif

When I create a `.gif` file in Photoshop, it works and animates. However, when I export it to a desktop it saves separate frames as GIFs. How do I bundle it so I can save it as one animated loop file in Photoshop?

Comment: Are you using Save For Web and Devices?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**To keep your animations and optimize your gif**, you should use the "save for web" and you can find it in the export options, or use the shortcut Control + Alt (or Option) + Shift + Save.

[image: How to save for web]

**To verify your animation and set the loops,** look at the bottom right part of the "save for web" window, you will see a section named "animation".

You can set it to loop once, forever or a specific number of time. There's a play button and other controls that will let you preview your animation.

To have access to this menu, don't forget to select "gif"  as file format on the top right!

[image: Save for web and choose loops in Adobe Photoshop]

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl + Shift + Alt + S is a shortcut to save for web and devices, if you are happy with the preview, just hit save and that would be all.